# Dissecting a chain of inequalities?

Tags: complex-analysis

Refer to the following, where $R$ is some real number:

[image]

I'm having a bunch of trouble following each of these steps... Can someone walk through it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: use the lemma
$$\Bigl|\int_a^b f(\theta)\,d\theta\Bigr|\le\int_a^b |f(\theta)|\,d\theta\ ,$$
where $a,b$ are real with $a\le b$ and $f$ is a (possibly complex) function of a real variable.  Then note that
$$\eqalign{\bigl|e^{i(Re^{i\theta})^2}(iRe^{i\theta})\bigl|
  &=\bigl|e^{iR^2(\cos2\theta+i\sin2\theta)}(iRe^{i\theta})\bigl|\cr
  &=|e^{-R^2\sin2\theta}|\cdot|e^{iR^2\cos2\theta}|\cdot|i|\cdot|R|\cdot
    |e^{i\theta}|\cr}$$
and that $\sin2\theta\ge\sin\theta$ whenever $0\le\theta\le\pi/4$.

Step 2: draw on the same axes the graphs of $y=\sin\theta$ and $y=2\theta/\pi$.

Step 3: evaluate the (real) integral by standard methods.  Don't forget that $R$ and $\pi$ are easy, they are just constants.